Sequelize Multipple Database
I need some help with a problem where I'm trying to create two databases, their tables, and the relationships between them using Sequelize.
The issue arises when I attempt to establish a relationship between the tables of the two databases; the program crashes with an error.
Do you know of any solution for this within Sequelize, or if not, can you recommend a similar ORM for this purpose?
Here is my current solution, which is not working:
const baseConn = new Sequelize({
    dialect: "mysql",
    host: "localhost",
    username: "root",
    password: "",
    port: 3306,
    logging: false,
  });

  await baseConn.query(
    "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS teszt_company DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_hungarian_ci;"
  );

  const systemConn = new Sequelize({
    dialect: "mysql",
    host: "localhost",
    username: "root",
    password: "",
    port: 3306,
    logging: false,
    database: "teszt_system",
  });

  const companyConn = new Sequelize({
    dialect: "mysql",
    host: "localhost",
    username: "root",
    password: "",
    port: 3306,
    logging: false,
    database: "teszt_company",
  });

  const User = systemConn.define("users", {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
    },
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
  });

  const Project = companyConn.define("project", {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
    },
    name: {
      type: DataTypes.STRING,
    },
  });

  const Work = companyConn.define("work", {
    id: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true,
    },
    userId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    },
    projectId: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
    },
    time: {
      type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
      defaultValue: 8,
    },
  });

  Work.belongsTo(Project, {
    foreignKey: "projectId",
    as: "Project",
    onUpdate: "CASCADE",
    onDelete: "CASCADE",
  });

  Work.belongsTo(User, {
    foreignKey: "userId",
    as: "User",
    onUpdate: "CASCADE",
    onDelete: "CASCADE",
  });

  await companyConn.sync({ force: true });


How do you plan to make to work the SQL query across two DBs?
